# Headphones vibration work on Ubuntu 16.04 but not on Windows 10,why?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-10, audio, headphones

I use Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 dualboot and my headphones vibration don't work on Windows. That's the feature built in HS-G500V headphones. How can i fix this?

Comment: Is the vibration feature recognised in windows - is the correct driver installed?

Answer (score 0):

The vibration is based on the rhythm of music you play.

Plug the USB cable into your laptop, the vibration function is from the USB port when you power on, while the green light is on you can adjust the strength by pushing the switch.

You may try louder music to ensure the vibration function.